# How to restore removed line breaks on multiple emails at once in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have in Outlook 2007 a mail folder with many messages for which Outlook has removed line breaks (as it does it by default). Line breaks are important in these messages, so I want to restore them. It is simple to restore line breaks in a single message - if I click on a grey bar above the message that says "Extra line breaks in this message have been removed" (like the one below), then the text changes to "This message has extra line breaks" and the line breaks in the message are restored.

[image]

However, I won't do this on 2.5 thousand messages one by one, so I'm looking for a way to mark all the messages I want to change and make this change for all messages at once. Maybe using a macro, if needed. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: I **don't** want to turn this feature off altogether - I know there's a setting in options that turns it off. This feature works good on **most** messages, so I want to keep it on. However, there's a large group of specific messages, which I want to explicitly set to "This message has extra line breaks" state, without having to do it one by one for each message.

Comment: like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720921/vba-outlook-how-to-uncheck-remove-extra-line-breaks-in-plain-text ?

Comment: Programming and software development is offtopic here, sorry.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. Related answer from Stack Overflow is to uncheck an option in settings. I neither need this (because I can do that manually) nor want this (because this doesn't do what I need). This is not a programming question, I am looking for ANY way to do this, preferably without programming.

Comment: Asking for software recommendation is also offtopic here.

Comment: IF you uncheck that option in the settings, does it retroactively apply to all the emails in your folders, or does that only apply to emails received going forward?

Comment: It does retroactively apply to all the emails without exception. As I clarified in the edit, this is not what I want.